# Upload unsuccessful. Plugin name already used, please use another plugin name

Tags: buildfire

I'm setting up a new App in and tried upload Plugin in Plugin Manager on https://dev.buildfire.com Without success

upload magento2Plugin Plugin in Plugin Manager on https://dev.buildfire.com Without success

Upload unsuccessful. Plugin name already used, please use another plugin name.
or
Upload unsuccessful. Missing resource folder.

Answer (score 0):

1. Plugin Names need to be unique system-wide. So if you pick another name it should work
2. Below is the file structure you should be submitting in your zip (ref https://github.com/BuildFire/sdk/wiki/How-to-create-a-Plugin )

[image]

I hope this helps